# Vite.js build in Laravel 10 ignoring a module

Tags: laravel, import, build, vite

I'm currently working on an old laravel 5 project, migrating to laravel 10. I've set up Vite.js, but there's a problem during the build, the create.js file doesn't import, so I can't call "create" in my template like this:

```php
@push('js')
    <script>
        create.formAutocomplete({!! \json_encode($users) !!});
    </script>
@endpush
```

The module in question :

```js
var createPlanningModule = function () {
    var formAutocomplete = function (availableTags) {
    // ...

    return {
        formAutocomplete: formAutocomplete,
        formDatepicker: formDatepicker
    }
};

var create = new createPlanningModule();
```

My app.js file

```js
// import './a-utils.js';
// import './bootstrap';
// import './common.js';
import './create.js';
// import './industrious.js';
```

The problem seems to lie in the fact that Vite only imports dependencies that are actually used. However, I only use the module in the blade template (I need to retrieve the $users variable).
Is there any way of forcing the import of the module so that I can refer to it later?
I've tried this in the vite.config.js, but it doesn't work:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/sass/app.scss',"resources/js/app.js" ],
            refresh: true,
            optimizeDeps: {
                include: ['resources/js/create.js']     // or 'createPlanningModule',
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

I'm not very familiar with these js syntaxes, perhaps there's something to be corrected for the imports?